# UV: How to make selection vertical?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv

In the UV mode I want to make the UV selection from curved to vertical. How can I do that in an automatic way?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the mesh part you want to unwrap, press <kbd>U</kbd> button to get unwrap menu and select **Reset**
2. Press <kbd>U</kbd> button again and select **Follow Active Quads**

Comment: Thank you. After that is posible to put the UVs on the inside of the area of the texture? For example if I have a 512X512 texture to put the UV's to mach the rectangle.

Comment: Yes you can grab and scale the UV with G and S buttons

Comment: There is no automatic method?

Comment: the selection selected, in the UV editor CTRL + P.

Comment: Yes Packing with CTRL+P will position the UV scaled proportionally to the UV grid, but you still have to scale the UV